# Is adding *more* info to another person's answer bad?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I edited an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532394/how-do-you-take-only-odd-digits-in-an-int-and-add-them) question. I added two more ways of solving the problem in the existing answer. Another user (well, who is quite reliable) rolled back my edit. Was this edit wrong?.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.  You should not be editing answers to add entirely new content.  You should be editing answers to improve the presentation of the author's own content.

If you have new information that you would like to add then you can do so through either comments or your own answer.

Comment: Worth noting, as answers that were once correct _do_ fall out of date, editing a prominent answer to bring it back into correctness is perfectly acceptable. Edits for presentation, grammar, etc are great but don't hesitate to fix something that is just (now) plain wrong, especially if it is highly scored and/or accepted (also nice to leave a comment when you do). Editing was the answer to that particular problem, and a big reason why we have it.

Comment: I was merely *enhancing* the answer. The answer contained *almost* everything, adding two more lines to make it a good one would have been better than writing my own answer and (more or less copying 70% of the other answer) adding two more lines.Right?

Comment: @TheLostMind Doing that is not appropriate.  You could have either commented on the answer to ask the author to include that information, or you could have posted your own answer.  Going into another person's answer to just add a bunch of your own content is not acceptable.

Comment: @Servy - Ya. You are right. :)

Comment: This just happened to a post I edited and the user rolled it back. As the answer was almost correct I thought that editing it was better than writing out my own that was also the same, and at least the person who spotted the main errors would get the accept points. I have always encouraged others to edit my posts rather than leave comments. As it is was less work for me that way than to have to incorporate there info and then check back a few days later to see if they had removed there comments and if not flag them as obsolete. I will know for the future! Comment or add my own answer.

Answer (score 12):

The guideline I follow myself is based on how I would feel about someone editing my answers: **Don't put material in someone else's answer which could make them say “I didn't recommend that solution!”.** What if someone posted a comment asking for clarification of the added material?

If you think an answer could be much more complete if it covered additional options, this is an excellent time to **write your own answer**.

Some of my better answers have come from seeing existing answers and thinking they aren't complete — or that the answer to the actual question exists spread across several “I'd just like to add…” answers but not one truly complete answer to the question as asked. There's nothing wrong with posting answers that use ideas from other answers — just put them in your own words, and give credit for especially creative ones.